# find subtree from binary tree

Tags: c#

See below binary tree.
And see implementation of this algo here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379572(v=vs.80).aspx

```
                       1                           level 0
                2              3                   level 1
            4    5   6    7        level 2
       8       9  10   11  12  13   14 15          level 3
```

My question is: How do I discover subtree from this tree based on the level? Lets say I want to discover two leveled subtree from 15 numbered node. Then result should be

```
          3
      6       7
12     13     14     15
```

If I search 3 leveled tree then it should be returned me above described full tree from 1 to 15.

Give me suggest for any code or algorithm or function which should be resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you referring to BST, or just a binary tree? It should be pretty easy, either way. The real question is: How can you find the N'th parent of a node? That node is the sub-tree you are looking for. How would you find the immediate parent of a node?

Comment: I m referring to BST. But which traversal method is useful for finding this Nth Parent node. or do you have any algorithm?

Comment: No one is here who can add a function in the above given library to fulfill my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a Node class defined as:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node Left { get; set; }
    public Node Right { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Node(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

You can add the following two methods to this class to achieve what you're trying to do:

```
public Node GetSubtree(int value, int depth)
{
    int foundDepth;
    return GetSubtreeHelper(value, depth, out foundDepth);
}

private Node GetSubtreeHelper(int value, int depth, out int foundDepth)
{
    if (Value == value)
    {
        foundDepth = 0;
        return depth == foundDepth ? this : null;
    }
    if (Left != null)
    {
        var node = Left.GetSubtreeHelper(value, depth, out foundDepth);
        if (foundDepth != -1)
        {
            return ++foundDepth == depth ? this : node;
        }
    }
    if (Right != null)
    {
        var node = Right.GetSubtreeHelper(value, depth, out foundDepth);
        if (foundDepth != -1)
        {
            return ++foundDepth == depth ? this : node;
        }
    }
    foundDepth = -1;
    return null;
}
```

Testing this using the tree in your question:

```
GetSubtree(15, 0) = Node 15
GetSubtree(15, 1) = Node 7
GetSubtree(15, 2) = Node 3
GetSubtree(15, 3) = Node 1
GetSubtree(15, 4) = null
```

Comment: hi Indium, 
Thank you very much.
Let me test this code with BST algorithm implementation which is given in the question.

Comment: The tree in your example isn't a BST, so my code is designed to work for a general binary tree. The search phase could be optimized if this was intended to be for BSTs only.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I read some blogs and books for BST and I think you are right.
But can you give me some solution which will be fitted in above given example (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379572(v=vs.80).aspx).
thank you very much.
Or you suggest me some link for a BST where your given code be plugged in.

Comment: It should be possible to insert the GetSubtree and GetSubtreeHelper methods into the BinaryTreeNode<T> class from the link almost verbatim. The only real change is to adjust the "int value" parameters to be "T value". The method can then be exposed through the BinaryTree class by adding an identical GetSubtree method which calls Root.GetSubtree(...). Try it and let me know how what issues you have.

Comment: :@Iridium: Is this working without making any extension method?

Comment: Since you (presumably) have the code for the binary tree, given that you're copying it from the website you linked, this can be added directly to the classes (without needing extension methods).

Comment: :@Iridium: I have try to modify and add the below method which is suggested in the solution.


  private BinaryTreeNode<T> GetSubtreeHelper(T value, int depth, out int foundDepth)
        {
            if (Value == base.Value)
            {
                foundDepth = 0;
                return depth == foundDepth ? this : null;
            }
/** Other code
}

But what should I put in If condition so it will not give me error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6203/discussion-between-hiren-and-iridium)

Comment: :@Iridium: My email id is hiren.visavadiya@gmail.com. If you have time to change the code, then please do it and send me on this email id.
thank you very much.

Comment: :@Iridium: I implemented these both methods with the my code and it is working well, but it returns always null.